# ASP.NET MVC 2 RC2 Routing - How to clear low-level values when using ActionLink to refer to a higher level?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

*[NOTE: I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 RC2.]*

I have URLs like this:

> /customers/123/orders/456/items/index
>
> /customers/123/orders/456/items/789/edit

My routing table lists the most-specific routes first, so I've got:

```
// customers/123/orders/456/items/789/edit
routes.MapRoute(
    "item", // Route name
    "customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}/items/{itemId}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Items", action = "Details" }, // Parameter defaults
    new { customerId = @"\d+", orderId = @"\d+", itemId = @"\d+" } // Constraints
);

// customers/123/orders/456/items/index
routes.MapRoute(
    "items", // Route name
    "customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}/items/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Items", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
    new { customerId = @"\d+", orderId = @"\d+" } // Constraints
);
```

When I'm in the item "Edit" page, I want a link back up to the "Index" page. So, I use:

```
ActionLink("Back to Index", "index")
```

However, because there's an ambient item ID, this results in the URL:

> /customers/123/orders/456/items/789/index

...whereas I want it to "forget" the item ID and just use:

> /customers/123/orders/456/items/index

I've tried overriding the item ID like so:

```
ActionLink("Back to Index", "index", new { itemId=string.empty })
```

...but that doesn't quite work. What that gives me is:

> /customers/123/orders/456/items?itemId=789

**How can I persuade `ActionLink` to "forget" the item ID?**

---

**EDIT**: fixed question - I was referring to "order" where I meant "item".

**EDIT**: added detail of why itemId=string.empty doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constraint you can delete any routeValues you do not need.

```
values.Remove("itemId");
```

Then create a class that inherits from IRouteConstraint.

Then in the Match method clear your route value and return true (indicates the route matches).

```
public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
{

    values.Remove("itemId");    
    return true;
}
```

then in Global.asax.cs change

```
new { customerId = @"\d+", orderId = @"\d+" }
```

to

```
new { customerId = @"\d+", orderId = @"\d+", custom=new MyNewConstraint() }
```

Comment: Sounds good, but what do you mean "in your constraint"? Where does this bit of code go?

Comment: Wow. I salute your knowledge of the routing infrastructure. I guess I could create a constraint class that accepts a list of (names of) route values to ignore in the constructor. But, it still seems like too much of an intervention to me - both in terms of the amount of code written and the extent to which you have to go against the grain. Personally, I think this should work out of the box - it seems like an oversight. I'll accept your answer, but actually I've "solved" the problem by putting a constraint on the action parameter as per my own answer. A zero-code solution is easiest for me.

Comment: I'll agree with that. How much of our jobs is making it work like it should though?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my previous answer, didn't notice they were the same controller.  Try setting itemId = string.empty.  This will make the first route fail, as it requires a digit in that position.

```
ActionLink("Back to Index", "index", new { itemId=string.empty })
```

Optionally you can create a link with the name of the route "item" manually

```
<%= Url.RouteUrl("item", new { controller="Items", action="Index", orderId=3 ... }) %>
```

Comment: @Jab: please see my edited answer as to why itemId=string.empty doesn't quite do the trick.

Comment: @Jab: RouteUrl does work, but it's a total pain to have to explicitly specify all the route values. (ActionLink has made me lazy). However, I did have success with RouteLink - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've got this to do what I want, by using RouteLink instead of ActionLink:

```
RouteLink("Back to Index", "items", new { action="index" })
```

...where the 2nd parameter is the name of the route I want to explicitly invoke.

---

**EDIT**: I didn't really want to go through all my dozens of `ActionLinks` and put them in this form, so instead I've modified the "item" rule to include a constraint on the `{action}` parameter, so that "index" does not match this route. Thus, it matches the "items" route instead - which has no `itemId` parameter. That seems to be a simpler way to do this, since the bulk of my code is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution at the root of the problem

It seems that the optimal solution (that doesn't smell like a workaround) is the one that solves the problem where it has roots and that's in routing.

I've written a custom `Route` class called `RouteWithExclusions` that is able to define route value names that should be excluded/removed when generating URLs.

The whole problem is detailed and explained in [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/removing-route-values-from-linksurls-in.html) and all the code is provided there as well. Check it out, it may help you solve this routing problem without the use of constraints but with a route that does what's required.