# mvc2.net how to remove ambient route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

in my mvc2 application i have an action link like

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("dash.board", "Index", pck.Controller,  new{docid ="",id = pck.PkgID }, new { @class = "here" })%>
```

docid is set to empty string because i want to clear ambient value of docid that is present in request context. i have gone through a lot of material on internet and even tried docid=String.Empty but it does not solve the problem and gives me url like /controller/action/id?docid=x. i also write a routeconstraint as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500997/asp-net-mvc-2-rc2-routing-how-to-clear-low-level-values-when-using-actionlink-t)  but it did not solve the problem either. plz suggest me a way to clear those route values comming from request context with html.actionLink. i don't want to use html.routeLink

Comment: What happens if you don't include the `docid` parameter: `<%=Html.ActionLink("dash.board", "Index", pck.Controller,  new{ id = pck.PkgID }, new { @class = "here" })%>`? Is it appending the `docid` value from the request url?

Comment: yes it does append docid from request url :(

Comment: Have you solved this Muhammad?

Comment: @Robert unfortunately i could not return to this problem seeing priority of other tasks.

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid: Check my answer below. I've provided a solution for you. You've probably solved this long time ago, but it may come in handy when others bump into the same problem.

Comment: @Robert i just have just gone through your post and it seems awesome +1 for that. i will return to it in the evening and i think this is probably the post that deserves to be marked as answer. thanks for writing so wonderful post

Answer (score 2):

### Solution at the root of the problem

It seems that the optimal solution (that doesn't smell too much as a workaround) is the one that solves the problem where it has roots and that's in routing.

I've written a custom `Route` class called `RouteWithExclusions` that is able to define route value names that should be excluded/removed when generating URLs.

The whole problem is detailed and explained in [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/removing-route-values-from-linksurls-in.html) and all the code is provided there as well. Check it out, it may help you solve this routing problem. I've also written two additional `MapRoute` extension methods that take an additional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is such a frustrating problem and I would venture to say that it is even a bug in ASP.Net MVC. Luckily it's an easy fix using ActionFilters. If you are using MVC3 then I would just put this as a global attribute to clear out ambient values. I made this attribute discriminatory, but you can change it to clear all attributes.

The assumption here is that by the time the Result is executing (your view most likely), you have already explicitly specified all your ActionLinks and Form Actions. Thus this will execute before they (the links) are evaluated, giving you a new foundation to generate them.

```
public class ClearAmbientRouteValuesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    private readonly string[] _keys;

    public ClearAmbientRouteValuesAttribute(params string [] keys)
    {
        if (keys == null)
            _keys = new string[0];

        _keys = keys;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        foreach (var key in _keys) {
            // Why are you sticking around!!!
            filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Remove(key);        
        }
    }
}

// Inside your Global.asax
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new ClearAmbientRouteValuesAttribute("format"));
}
```

Hope this helps someone, cause it sure helped me. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: Well this is not desired. I want just certain link to remove particular route values but other should use it. On the same view. This will remove it globally for all views forever.

Comment: yeah you are right that this will remove it for global views, but I personally wanted that because I always have all the values that I want to use when creating a route. Sorry it wasn't helpful. Your option then would be to overwrite or create a new route link builder. :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but I'm dealing with this issue in MVC5. For what it's worth, this seems to work for me, and I leave it here for others to try...

On the site I'm working on, I have a controller action that takes a date as a parameter like this:

`http://localhost:9999/DailyActivity/2014-01-01`

But in the page, I need links that resolve to

`http://localhost:9999/DailyActivity`

or

`http://localhost:9999/DailyActivity/Index`

Using this

`@Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "Index", "DailyActivity")`

Frustratingly creates links like this:

`http://localhost:9999/DailyActivity/2014-01-01`

This does not help:

`@Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "Index", "DailyActivity", new { date = String.Empty }, null)`

As it creates a link like this:

`http://localhost:9999/DailyActivity?date=2014-01-01`

After banging my head, the solution I found *seems* to work. Put a slash in the action name (before or after). The ambient date value is then discarded:

`@Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "/Index", "DailyActivity")`

That generates:

`http://localhost:9999/DailyActivity/Index`

And

`@Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "/Index/..", "DailyActivity")`

Gives

`http://localhost:9999/DailyActivity`

I don't yet know what kind of ramifications this has in the routing system, but it seems to work...

**EDIT:**

It might be a better idea to do this (for the default action):

`@Html.ActionLink("Test Link", String.Empty, "DailyActivity")`