# Action Link to "lose" parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink

I've got the following routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(null,"Conference/{shortName}/Submission/{submission}/{action}", new { controller = "Conference", action = "Show" });
routes.MapRoute(null,"Conference/{shortName}/{action}",new { controller = "Conference", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

The following (hopefully obvious) links which are all working:

- /Conference/testconf
- /Conference/testconf/ShowSubmissions
- /Conference/testconf/Submission/firstSub
- /Conference/testconf/Submission/firstSub/EditSubmission

When I'm now in Submission/firstSub and create a ActionLink like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show Submissions", "ShowSubmissions", "Conference", new { shortName = Model.confereceShortName },null)
```

it creates the following Link

- /Conference/testconf/Submission/firstSub/ShowSubmissions

How can i let the actionlink forget about Submission/firstSub without hardcoding it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes searching for 30min isn't enough, you gotta search 2h...

[ASP.NET MVC 2 RC2 Routing - How to clear low-level values when using ActionLink to refer to a higher level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500997/asp-net-mvc-2-rc2-routing-how-to-clear-low-level-values-when-using-actionlink)

Routlink or delete the values in the constraints.
For me Routelink does the job.

Although Thanks

ElYusubov & Aleksey

Answer (score 1):

Where do you have a placeholder for `{controller}`?

The default route should look like the following sample.

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{*id}", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
                );
```

Also try to remove the /Submission/ part in your first route.
Links for posts on custom route creation and ordering:

1) [Creating Custom Routes (C#)](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx)

2) [Custom routing for ASP .NET MVC](http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/05/26/custom-routing-for-asp-net-mvc/)

3) [official source from asp.net mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)

Comment: My two routes are between the ignore and the default route you posted, should have mentioned that. I only want the Conference controller to handle the two requests. Also the Link should either look like /Conference/confID/Submission/subID or /Conference/confID.

The Links are working, i only want a "back" button from /conf/confid/sub/subid to /conf/confid

Comment: As mentioned, try to re-oder your routes that may definitely help. Also look at custom route links on my answer that will help.

Comment: when reordering my actionLink generates the following Link /Conference/testconf/Show?submission=firstSub (cause the first one matches now). Concerning your Links, I already create my custom route the main problem I have now is getting out from a subroute to a mainroute. I also edited my other route mapping in my question.